# Multidimensional CLT for Exchangeable Random Variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT)

Let $\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2, ..., \mathbf{X}_n$ be *independent* $d$ dimensional random vectors having $0$ mean. Let $\mathbf{S}=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ be the invertible covariance of $\mathbf{S}$. Let  $\mathbf{Z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$.

Then for all convex $U$, 
$$\big| \mathbb{P}[\mathbf{S} \in U] - \mathbb{P}[\mathbf{Z} \in U] \big| \leq C d^{1/4} \gamma,$$

where $\gamma = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big\Vert \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1/2}X_i \big\Vert^3_2.$

Obviously this still applies if the $\mathbf{X}_i$ are additionally identically distributed, so that they are IID.

Does a *multi-variate* CLT exist for *exchangeable* random variables? If it helps, the Berry-Esseen bound is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure what the flaws are. It is true that there is nothing about the limit as $n \to \infty$ in the statement; for this one must appropriately scale the $\mathbf{X}_i$s and the covariance has to be such that $\gamma \to 0$. What is wrong with that?

I don't understand the Poisson-distributed example. The expected value of $1/2000$ means that these random variables don't satisfy the requirement in the first sentence.